# jQuery / Ajax: How to pass JS variable to specific PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am new to PHP and never used Ajax before so I hope someone can help me with this.

I have a **separate functions.js file that stores all the JS** I use for the pages of a website.
So far all the exchange with the db is done with PHP directly on the pages which works fine so far but now I have a scenario where I need to initiate this from the JS file.

My thought was I could create a separate PHP file (ajax.php) that hosts functions just for such purposes and then **pass data via Ajax from the JS file to this PHP file**.

So far I have the following but since there are multiple functions on the ajax.php file I am not sure how to pass this to the specific function I need. 
Also, I am not sure if the Ajax call I have is set up correctly.

Can someone help me with this and maybe also explain your answer in a few words ?
Basically, here I want to pass the JS variable "`itemID`" to the PHP function fetchTransMain where this should be used for the variable `$itemID` (the variable $trans is generated in PHP).

**Update:** I would also need to know how to get the result from the PHP function back in JS. I didn't find an approach for this yet, perhaps with an Ajax GET call ??

**What I have in my functions.js file:**

```
var itemID = "someID";

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "post",
    cache: "false",
    data: itemID,
    success: function(){
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

**...and on my ajax.php file:**

```
function fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID){
    foreach($trans as $key => $val){
        if($val["ID"] == $itemID){
            echo $val["trans"];
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: You need to look for `$_POST['data']` to bring in the passed data

Comment: Usually I separate the PHP functions, one per file. But you could send something in your data (the function name) and check for it in PHP to decide which function to execute.

Comment: You can not call a specific PHP function from the “outside” via an HTTP request. What you can do, is send a parameter to tell the PHP script which functionality to execute, and use a `switch` statement in your PHP script to call a specific function based on that value.

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks - the switch is a great solution for this ! Will definitely apply that.

Comment: [Here are the basics](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) along with troubleshooting ideas and techniques.

Comment: Another approach could be to instead of using `switch`, pass the function name directly, and call it via `call_user_func`/`call_user_func_array` – but with that approach, it would be _absolutely mandatory_ to check if the passed value is the name of an _allowed_ function first (f.e. using `in_array` with an array of allowed function names), otherwise an attacker could execute any arbitrary PHP function on your server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define data as an object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "post",
    cache: "false",
    data: {itemId: itemID},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

And then:

```
$itemId = $_POST['itemId'];
function fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID){
    foreach($trans as $key => $val){
        if($val["ID"] == $itemID){
            echo $val["trans"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great - thanks a lot ! How would I get the result from PHP back in JS ? Same thing just with get instead of post ?

Comment: check my edit. in your success function, you get as first parameter the response of your php. If you want to send multiple values back to your js, checkout the json_encode function in php.net

Comment: This is perfect - thanks again ! Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest you to read some tutorial about ajax and PHP because there are so many aspects involved in this question that we can't explain them all in one answer. Anyway what you want to do is very common, you have a value in your browser that you want to save on your server.

The first part is almost correct:

```
    $.ajax({
         url: "ajax.php",
         type: "post",
         cache: "false",
         data: {valueName: itemID},
         success: function(){
             alert("success");
         },
         error: function(){
             alert("failure");
         }
     });
```

Just pay attantion to the data parameter, you should pass an object there with a name. That name is the name that you'll use on PHP to retrieve the value.

Then on server side:

```
function fetchTransMain($trans, $itemID){
    foreach($trans as $key => $val){
        if($val["ID"] == $itemID){
            echo $val["trans"];
        }
    }
}

$valueFromClient = $_POST['valueName'];
fetchTransMain($trans, $valueFromClient);
```

Here you have to use $_POST since we have choose type: "post" on the client side.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot - the explanations are really good. This is similar to what taxicala suggested and he was a bit earlier so I'll accept his answer but voted you up and the explanations definitely helped - A LOT. :)

Comment: Thanks anyway for your upvote :D